# SHAP values vs logistic regression

Tags: machine-learning, shapley-value

I read many articles about SHAP values and I get the general theory behind it. However, there's something that I have a difficulty with.

When we try to explain LR models, we explain it in terms of odds. For exmaple: Males have two times the odds of females, while keeping everything else constant.
In SHAP summary plots, we can see the tendancies of variables and how they effect the outcome. However, do we have that "while keeping everything else constant" interpretation or not. From what I understood, that is not the case. Feel free to correct me and to add to the theory to help me understand. Much appreciated !